# Automation of Oracle queries in chef recipe

Tags: oracle, automation, chef-infra, recipe

I want to automate oracle queries to configure database in oracle. Can some one help me any market place cookbook or sample code how to run oracle query in chef recipe

Command : ALTER SYSTEM SET REMOTE_LOGIN_PASSWORDFILE=EXCLUSIVE SCOPE=SPFILE;

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is include all your queries in a .sql file and execute it using Chef's EXECUTE resource.

Comment: How to check for idempotency gaurd conditions. Any best practices available for this kind of implementation where we have to run commands in different prompt like rman and sqlplus